# How to use variables in external script.js in vue component sigle-file

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a `.js` file with variables. Every array item is an array of `[lat, lng]` google maps objects.
I would to use them in a single-file vue component.
How to do it?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you have and what you want to achieve? You can export each variable and then import in your vue file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your file is a module, fe:

```
// points.js
export default [
    [1.247, 2.8542],
    [1.854, 2.9854]
]
```

You can import it into component ans assign it to its data:

```
// component.vue
import latLngPoints from 'points.js';

export default {
   ... 
   data () {
       return {
            points: latLngPoints
        } 
   } 
}
```

Theny you can use it in your component as `this.points` or just `{{ points }}` in the template.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my file is not a module. It contains: var z1=[{lat:40,12}] and var z2=[{lat:39,10}] with thousends lines.

Comment: I transformed this file in module and it work fine. Thank you